# Edit specific cell of csv to write result of execution - java. record gets appended but not replaced

Tags: java, csv

I have an issue when trying to edit specific data into csv file.

input csv(inputfile.csv) :

```
username,password,status
uname1,pwd1,todo
uname2,pwd2,todo
uname3,pwd2,pass
```

required output in same csv(inputfile.csv) :

```
username,password,status
uname1,pwd1,pass
uname2,pwd2,pass
uname3,pwd2,pass
```

I tried to do this using apache poi for csv operation as well as OpenCSV. but I cold append the new result like :

```
username,password,status
uname1,pwd1,todo
uname2,pwd2,todo
uname3,pwd2,pass
uname1,pwd1,pass
```

Unable to replace the existing record. can someone please suggest any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void updateCSV(String fileToUpdate, String replace,
    int row, int col) throws IOException {

File inputFile = new File(fileToUpdate);

// Read existing file 
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(inputFile), ',');
List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();
// get CSV row column  and replace with by using row and column
csvBody.get(row)[col] = replace;
reader.close();

// Write to CSV file which is open
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(inputFile), ',');
writer.writeAll(csvBody);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
}
```

Comment: I tried this . but after writing csvBody to the same csv file, added data are surrounded by " ". i,e. "keyword","apiresult". because of which this does not work when the function called next time for another data edit

Answer (score 0):

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Downloads\\spred.csv",
      true));
String [] record = "user7,pwd10,pass".split(",");     
writer.writeNext(record);   
System.out.println("Write succesfully");      
writer.close();
```